# How to Set the Background Color Behind a .png Background in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

So I have a set of .png pictures that have a transparent background that will be on a checkerboard. When a playing piece is clicked, the possible places that the piece can move to will change color. However, I want to know if in setting the background color of a tile and if the tile has an opposing piece on it, will the picture of the opposing piece be overridden and erased in favor of the color. And if it is erased, how can I avoid this problem?

This is the call I used to set the background as the .png file

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fileName);
```

This is the call I used to set the background as the color

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.COLOR);
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @Raheel138 I've used btn.setBackgroundResource() and btn.setBackgroundColor()

Comment: use LayerDrawable in java or <layer-list> in xml